Unity Hub not opening any projects
I recently downloaded Unity on my Mac, but none of my projects are opening. Here are the error messages I am getting: The error message
\"ERROR.PROJECT.PATH_NOT_FOUND\",\"projectName\":\"Test-1\",\"projectVersion\":\"2022.3.27f1\",

I am new to Unity and Unity Hub, and I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried multiple projects, but none of them will open. I also have two different versions of Unity on my computer, for some reason, one with a logo, and the other without one.

posting things as pictures is not how SO is for, how can people search for text to see if this is what they have if you post as a picture? as for not opening? Path not found seems pretty clear..

This looks like a permissions issue:
Unity FAQ
This points to an Apple forum.
Ultimately, it looks like you need to enable the root user or grant your user permission.
